# Verify a PDF byte array with Verify.ImageMagick

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, pdf, verify-tests

With [Verify.ImageMagick](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify.ImageMagick), it's possible to verify PDF files by them being converted to images which are then diffed. The default is naturally to compare files on disk, but I would like to verify a `byte` array. As I can't use `ImplicitUsings`, I have the following NUnit test:

```cs
[Test]
public void VerifyPdf()
{
    var byteArray = GeneratePdf();
    Verifier.Verify(byteArray).UseExtension("pdf");
}
```

I've added [Verify.NuNit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Verify.NUnit/) to the test project, I've installed [Verify support in Rider](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17240-verify-support) and to initialize ImageMagic, I have this setup fixture:

```cs
[SetUpFixture]
public class PdfTestsSetup
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        VerifyImageMagick.RegisterPdfToPngConverter();
    }
}
```

Still, when I run the `VerifyPdf` test in Rider, it becomes successful, there's no output logged to the console, and "Compare Received/Verified" in Rider does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As answered on GitHub](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Discussions/discussions/24#discussioncomment-2499340), the result of `Verifier.Verify()` needs to be awaited:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task VerifyPdf()
{
    var byteArray = GeneratePdf();
    await Verifier.Verify(byteArray).UseExtension("pdf");
}
```